# Use primary_key only for one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to manage some users for a club in a rails application. Every member needs to apply for the club first. Therefore, my application has a User model, an Application model and some others for different purposes. I want to associate the applications with a specific user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :applications
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

end
```

and

```
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Since the applications don't contain the User ID, I have set the foreign and primary keys manually:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :applications, :foreign_key => 'email', :primary_key => 'email'
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

end

class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'email', :primary_key => 'email'
end
```

However, this does not work for me. See rails console output:

```
2.2.1 :001 > User.all
  User Load (4.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, email: "example@gmail.com", name: "example", created_at: "2016-07-05 20:29:06", updated_at: "2016-07-07 08:59:56", admin: true>]> 
2.2.1 :002 > Application.all
  Application Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "applications".* FROM "applications"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Application id: 1, email: "example@gmail.com", first_name: "Example", last_name: "User", work: "Example", location: "NYC", created_at: "2016-07-07 14:46:40", updated_at: "2016-07-07 14:46:40">]> 
2.2.1 :003 > User.first.applications
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Application Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "applications".* FROM "applications" WHERE "applications"."email" = ?  [["email", "example@gmail.com"]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

I know that it is possible to change the primary key for the user model with self.primary_key to email but I would like to use the regular ID still with some other associations.

Comment: It's possible, but why would you want to do it, why not just put user_id in the applications? It not only is the rails way but it's also the database normalization way...you're repeating data in applications you don't have to repeat.

Comment: The data is coming from outside, so where would the user_id be populated from?

Comment: Then why is the user model linked to the application model at all?  It's unclear to me what your model set up is trying to devise.  If people must 'apply' before they become 'users' - then perhaps alter your user table to have an 'applicant' toggle - the 'accept' or 'decline' the application.  Repeating data is never a good idea if you can avoid it.  I think a bit more explanation of the functionality would work.  (And you can over ride any functionality in ruby that you want, [start here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) with your research